# change header to part name (classicthesis)

Tags: header-footer, classicthesis

I would like to change the header from chapter without number (left) and section with number (right) to part without number (left) and chapter with number (right):

```
\documentclass[twoside,openright,titlepage,numbers=noenddot,headinclude,
    footinclude=true,cleardoublepage=empty,
    BCOR=5mm,paper=a4,fontsize=10pt]{scrbook}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\usepackage[parts,beramono,eulerchapternumbers,%
listings,manychapters,%
floatperchapter]{classicthesis} 

\begin{document}
\pagestyle{scrheadings}
\part{Introduction}
\chapter{First chapter}
\section{First section}
\lipsum[1-18]
\section{Second section}
\lipsum[1-12]
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`classicthesis` loads `scrpage2`. You can use

```
  \automark[chapter]{part}
  \renewcommand{\partmark}[1]{\markboth{\spacedlowsmallcaps{#1}}{}}
```

[image]
[image]

Code:

```
\documentclass[twoside,openright,titlepage,numbers=noenddot,headinclude,
    footinclude=true,cleardoublepage=empty,
    BCOR=5mm,paper=a4,fontsize=10pt]{scrbook}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\usepackage[parts,beramono,eulerchapternumbers,%
listings,manychapters,%
floatperchapter]{classicthesis} 
%
  \automark[chapter]{part}
  \renewcommand{\partmark}[1]{\markboth{\spacedlowsmallcaps{#1}}{}}
%
\begin{document}
\pagestyle{scrheadings}
\part{Introduction}
\chapter{First chapter}
\section{First section}
\lipsum[1-18]
\section{Second section}
\lipsum[1-12]
\part{Main}
\chapter{Second chapter}
\section{First section}
\lipsum[1-18]
\section{Second section}
\lipsum[1-12]
\end{document}
```

Comment: Unfortunately this only works for the MWE. In my document I use

`\documentclass[twoside,openright,titlepage,numbers=noenddot,headinclude, footinclude=true,cleardoublepage=empty,abstractoff, BCOR=5mm,paper=a4,fontsize=11pt,ngerman,american]{scrreprt}
\input{classicthesis-config}`

from classicthesis package instead of 
`\documentclass[twoside,openright,titlepage,numbers=noenddot,headinclude,
    footinclude=true,cleardoublepage=empty,
    BCOR=5mm,paper=a4,fontsize=10pt]{scrbook}
\usepackage[parts,beramono,eulerchapternumbers,%
listings,manychapters,%
floatperchapter]{classicthesis}`

Comment: The MWE works for me if I use your changed preamble. Did you customize the `classicthesis-config` or is the tableofcontents (or something like that) inside a part?

Comment: ok, I've found the mistake... within my document I loaded the content-file of the classicthesis package. within this there was already an automark definition. So I replaced this with your command and everything is fine now. Thanks a lot!